# Is "eventide" a correct word for the kanji 汐

Tags: kanji

Jisho dictionary refers to 汐 as the kanji for **eventide**, tide, salt water, opportunity. looking in Oxford dictionary, eventide means *The end of the day; evening.*

I don't see how 汐 has anything to do with "eventide" apart from the way they look. I am curious to know why it is so commonly referred to as one of the meanings of the kanji?

Comment: Probably just a Heisig keyword and not a definition…

Comment: I see the point. So it is common to see this sort of thing when it comes to kanji?

Comment: I don't know where Heisig got the keyword from, but the connection between 汐 and 夕 is more than just a similar appearance.

Comment: @droooze True! Maybe it is just a sort of step for beginners who are still outside the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not correct in the very strictest sense.「汐」means *evening tide*, and **the character** is never used to just mean *evening*.

<sub>There's a suggestion that whoever came up with the meaning *eventide* thought it meant *evening tide*, but I can't confirm this.</sub>

---

The real story is slightly more complicated. Notice how [潮汐]{ちょうせき} (*morning and evening tides*) forms an exact analogous pair to [朝夕]{ちょうせき} (*morning and evening*); in fact, they're *cognates* in Old Chinese and have become homophones in Japanese. Naturally, this is because there is a tight association between tides and the time of day.

According to [Zhengzhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)),「汐」and「夕」were both **/*ljaːɡ/**, so we can view them as representing exactly the same word - that is, there was originally one word for both *evening* and *evening tide*, and the different *kanji* were used to provide the different nuances.

So, while *eventide* is not correct for the *kanji*「汐」, it is correct for the word that「汐」represents, which is the same word as that which「夕」represents.

---

> A note on *kanji* usage: In Japanese,「汐」can sometimes be used as a generic representation of *tide*, in which case it is interchangeable with「潮」. The word(s) that both「汐」and「潮」represents in this interchangeable case is しお/うしお. However,「汐」shouldn't be used for *morning tide*, so「あさしお」should not be written as「朝汐」. The reverse isn't true due to *Jōyō kanji* standardisation:「汐」is not a *Jōyō kanji*, so「潮」has taken over the function of「汐」for the word(s) しお/うしお. This means that *evening tide* can be written as「夕潮」, and is the standard Japanese representation.

Comment: FWIW, according to the [Unihan Database Lookup tool](http://unicode.org/charts/unihan.html) provided by the Unicode Consortium, the definition for the character [汐 U+6C50](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E6%B1%90) is "night tides, evening ebb tide", but the [kDefinition](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/index.html#kDefinition) field is supposed to be pan-CJK, not Japanese-specific...

Comment: @Mikaeru edited to address your comment.

Comment: Speaking of tides, the ocean of 漢字 is not only *wide* but also quite *deep*. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. いつも勉強になります！

Comment: @Mikaeru actually, thank you for reminding me to put that *kanji* usage note in. I originally answered this question as if it was a Chinese language question, and totally forgot the complications of *kun'yomi* and Japanese orthography.